# Minimum Width Scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a bit of a rough time trying to figure out why my content at minimum page width is generating a scroll bar with Bootstrap 3. I've narrowed down the code to the following, but I'm not quite sure what is causing it. I've done a  tonne of stuff to try and fix it but can't point my finger on it.

```
<div ng-view="">
    <div class="section-a">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-push-1 col-xs-12 text-right">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default feedback-top">Feedback</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <div class="forward">
                         <h1>Header</h1>

                         <h2>Header2</h2>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section-d">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row vertical-align">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-1 col-xs-12 text-center">Here is some text</p>
                    <p class="lead">Here is some more text</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 text-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn "btn-default">Feedback</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot of the problem and a jsfiddle, any help would be greatly appreciated: https://jsfiddle.net/hzjuoksg/1/

[image]

Comment: Give the size of text in `em` instead of `px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is wider than it's parent (this is called overflow). By default, overflow is visible, which causes the scrollbar to appear.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

> The overflow property specifies whether to clip content, render
>   scrollbars or just display content when it overflows its block level
>   container.

If you don't want your content to overflow, use `overflow: hidden`.

For example:

```
.section-a {
    background-color: red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.section-b {
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hzjuoksg/2/

Comment: if he really doesn't want any scrollbars, he must set the body to overflow:hidden; too https://jsfiddle.net/hzjuoksg/3/

Comment: I understand what overflow is, but I'm mostly trying to figure out if there's a solution outside of hiding it. I want it to cascade/resize like you'd expect a responsive page to do. The issue I'm running into is that these overflowed containers are causing my entire page design to look wrong on a mobile device.

Comment: @RachelGallen `overflow: hidden` on the body also prevents vertical scrolling. Not ideal. Of course, you could just use `overflow-x: hidden`, but I've had issue with that in the past.

Comment: @JamesIves Use media queries to resize the text based on width. Smaller font size for small screens etc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Bah, I guess I was just hoping bootstrap would do all those nice things for me :( thanks for the reply!

Comment: @JamesIves Ah, I now understand what you want. Unfortunately CSS doesn't have responsive font sizes. Technically you could use `vw` widths for fonts, but I certainly wouldn't rely on it. At the moment, there's no way for CSS to detect if there's overflow and adjust the font size accordingly (although it would be very useful!). The most bulletproof solution is to control the sizes yourself with media queries.

Comment: @ChristianVarga Gotcha, I did not know that so now your responses make much more sense to me now. :)